# How do you get the related articles cluster in a Google News RSS feeds?

Tags: rss, google-news

Google includes the following requirement to use there RSS news feeds:

> Include a link to the Google News cluster of related articles for each
>   news item, using the link provided in the Google News feed.

This link should have a collection of other articles that are related to the current item. One of the xml properties in each nodes in there RSS feeds is something that looks like this:

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">tag:news.google.com,2005:cluster=43982360597436</guid>
```

However, I'm not able to figure out how to use this to get a list of related articles. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be looking at the top of the RSS feed, and in particular the `<link>` node which contains the link to the news cluster.

For example:

```
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <generator>NFE/1.0</generator>
    <title>Google News</title>
    <link>http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&ned=us&hl=en&topic=snc&ncl=dd_4rHFR0wfHJ5M35r9VmSXgpLESM</link>
    <language>en</language>
    <webMaster>news-feedback@google.com</webMaster>
    <copyright>&amp;copy;2014 Google</copyright>
    <pubDate>Tue, 19 Aug 2014 03:31:53 GMT</pubDate>
    <lastBuildDate>Tue, 19 Aug 2014 03:31:53 GMT</lastBuildDate>
    ...
```

Here, the URL in the `<link>` node will take you to [a page showing all related articles](http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&ned=us&hl=en&topic=snc&ncl=dd_4rHFR0wfHJ5M35r9VmSXgpLESM) which forms the news cluster.

Comment: Wow... I never would have guessed to look at that field. Thanks!